# Assign the object reference not the object

Tags: oop, julia

I have come across a problem with bindings in Julia
When trying to do this:

```
type Chain
    value :: Int
    son :: Chain

    #Make the last link in the chain point to itself
    #so as to spare us from the julia workaround for nulls
    Chain(value::Int) = (chain = new(); chain.value = value; chain.son = chain; chain)
end

#Create three separate nodes
c=Chain(5)
d=Chain(2)
e=Chain(1)

#Link an object to another and then modify the linked object
c.son = d
son = d.son
son = e
c
```

I would like to change the link for the son in the parent, but it only works if I do this:

```
c.son = d
d.son = e
c
```

This creates a problem in recursive functions, where if you pass an object to the function which is linked to another object and change it in the body of the function then the link isn't changed, only the object itself.

I have tried using the julia function `pointer_from_objref`, but this used for handling c functions and the assigning with `unsafe_store!` didn't work.

How would I go about to create a variable that when assigned to also changes the link to which I referred to?

Comment: The claim that what Julia does here is different from what Java or C# do seems incorrect. All of the above languages implement mutable objects in the same way – effectively as pointers to C structs. If you believe that Java or C# do something different, it would be good to see an example.

Comment: Well, if we look at the [snippet](https://github.com/ravikanthreddy89/LeftLeaningRedBlackTrees/blob/acfb7c1d818e300f9e1fa3896ca3b041a9becb6d/src/RedBlackBST.java#L64-L73) @Gnimuc Key posted, the problem lies in the put method. One assigns the new rotated node like this `if(!isRed(x.left) && isRed(x.right)) x=rotateLeft(x);` Put is a recursive method, so x will be the son of another node. In Java the object returned by `rotateright` will be assigned to the son of the object before the recursion. In Julia this won't happen.

Comment: Here is a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/netoelgrande/ea3b5cea4111d3ba66b0) where I show a translation of the previous snippet in julia. The analogue to the put method is in the add_node method.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that `son = x` in a Java method of an object that has a `son` field will assign to the field, whereas object fields can only be assigned by the explicitly qualified `obj.son = x` syntax?

Comment: An alternative interpretation is that you mean `&son = d.son` which would work in C++, but not in Java or C#.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the first fact. Are you maybe implying that if I do `son=x` in a method outside the object it will not assign to the field?

Comment: Ah, ok. Since Julia methods don't belong to one of the arguments, which object's `son` field would you expect such an assignment to alter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91525/discussion-between-ernesto-paas-and-stefankarpinski).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood you property, you can declare `son` as an `Array`=>`son::Array{Chain,1}` to achieve this.

```
type Chain
    value::Int
    son::Array{Chain,1}
    Chain(value::Int) = (chain = new(); chain.value = value; chain.son = [chain]; chain)
end

julia> c=Chain(5)
Chain(5,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])

julia> d=Chain(2)
Chain(2,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])

julia> e=Chain(1)
Chain(1,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])

julia> c.son = [d]
1-element Array{Chain,1}:
 Chain(2,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])

julia> son = d.son
1-element Array{Chain,1}:
 Chain(2,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])

julia> son[:] = e
Chain(1,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])

julia> c
Chain(5,[Chain(2,[Chain(1,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])])])
```

this is because by running `son = d.son` and `son = e`, you just entirely change the binding.

```
# NOT using array type
julia> son = d.son
Chain(2,Chain(#= circular reference =#))

julia> son = e
Chain(1,Chain(#= circular reference =#))

julia> son === d.son
false

# using array type
julia> son = d.son
1-element Array{Chain,1}:
 Chain(2,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])

julia> son[:] = e
Chain(1,[Chain(#= circular reference =#)])

julia> son === d.son
true
```

if you want to reserve the link, a workaround is to use array type and change the content of the array instead of its binding. [more details about bindings](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2014/09/06/values-vs-bindings-the-map-is-not-the-territory/).

Comment: Thanks, this does answer my question. But if I wanted to use this for a data structure wouldn't it affect performance?

Comment: It would also interest me to know why it isn't necessary to do this in C# or the likes.

Comment: can you please elaborate more about your data structure use cases?

Comment: Well, I'm translating the left-leaning red-black binary tree from Robert Sedgewick. So, one use case would be an efficient storing of ordered data. 
My problem lies in the rotate methods where a node changes places with one of its children. It's done like this `node = rotateright(node)`. Where the method returns the modified left node.
In the code I've seen (which is done with classes in Java and C#) there is no need to give a list or array type to the fields for the children.

Comment: if your use case looks like this java [snippets](https://github.com/ravikanthreddy89/LeftLeaningRedBlackTrees/blob/acfb7c1d818e300f9e1fa3896ca3b041a9becb6d/src/RedBlackBST.java#L64-L73), you do not need to link an object to another new one. take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/Gnimuc/090649bd51dd9518eb55).

Comment: until now, i still don't understand why you intend to use `son = d.son`&
`son = e`, so in my answer i only clarify how to fix this "binding" problem. it seems you just want a pointer? i'm not familiar with both java and C#, so there must be something wrong in my code. feel free to mark this question as unanswered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91287/discussion-between-gnimuc-key-and-ernesto-paas).